# How to project 3D human face mesh vertices on a cylindrical surface?

Tags: python, 3d, computational-geometry, uv-mapping, cylindrical

I am trying to implement a Pose Normalisation methodology as mentioned in the paper [LipSync3D](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.04185.pdf), where I need to project 3D human face mesh vertices on a cylindrical coordinate system with a vertical axis such that **most face vertices are equidistant from axis.**

To implement this, the paper refers to another paper called [OPTIMAL UV SPACES FOR FACIAL MORPHABLE MODEL CONSTRUCTION](https://ibug.doc.ic.ac.uk/media/uploads/documents/uv_spaces.pdf), which describes the methodology in the following section.

[Cylindrical Coordinate projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQcLe.png)

However, it is difficult to infer on how do 3D to 2D translation of mesh vertices to the z-x plane before applying the Coope's linear least squares method to fit the points optimally.

I tried the following, but its the wrong approach:

```html
import mediapipe.python.solutions.face_mesh as mp_face_mesh
import mediapipe.python.solutions.drawing_utils as mp_drawing
import mediapipe.python.solutions.drawing_styles as mp_drawing_styles
import cv2

# Landmarks to dict

def landmark_to_dict(landmark_list):
    landmark_dict = {}
    for idx, landmark in enumerate(landmark_list):
        landmark_dict[idx] = [landmark.x, landmark.y, landmark.z]

    return landmark_dict
    
# Path to a human face
image = cv2.imread('img0002.png')
image_rows, image_cols, _ = image.shape

with mp_face_mesh.FaceMesh(
    static_image_mode=True,
    max_num_faces=1,
    refine_landmarks=True,
    min_detection_confidence=0.5) as face_mesh:

    results = face_mesh.process(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    reference_dict = landmark_to_dict(results.multi_face_landmarks[0].landmark)
    


# Convert keypoints to np array
import numpy as np
arr = np.empty((0,3), int)
for i in range(len(reference_dict)):
    row = np.array(reference_dict[i])
    arr = np.vstack([arr,row])
    
    

import numpy as np
from ai import cs

# converting spherical spiral from spherical to cartesian coordinates
r, phi, z = cs.cart2cyl(
    x = arr[:,0],
    y = arr[:,1],
    z = arr[:,2]
)

# Calculate new projections (unclear on this step / just a guess)
r_new = (r - (y - x))**2

# cylindrical to cartesian
x_new, y_new, z_new = cs.cyl2cart(r=r_new, phi=phi, z=z)
```

If anyone could provide a pseudo code to implement this, that’d be very helpful.

Comment: Did you happen to try this https://github.com/menpo/menpo3d/blob/master/menpo3d/unwrap.py?